# Filter Pandas Dataframe by minute

Tags: python, pandas, filter

This is post is similar to other posts but the format of the date columns appears to be different in my case (I have a multi index with data and stock tickers)

2014-05-01 09:31:00+00:00

I would like to filter only this particular data/time, but this does not work and returns and empty dataframe:

```
data2=data.loc[('2014-05-01 09:32:00+00:00',slice(None)),:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""timestamp,dummy1,dummy2
2014-05-01 09:31:00+00:00,1,3
2014-05-01 09:32:00+00:00,2,4
"""
), parse_dates=['timestamp'])

# use a multi index
df = df.set_index(['timestamp', 'dummy1'])
```

---

```
                                  dummy2
timestamp                 dummy1        
2014-05-01 09:31:00+00:00 1            3
2014-05-01 09:32:00+00:00 2            4
```

---

filter on `2014-05-01 09:31`

```
df.loc['2014-05-01 09:31']
```

---

```
                                  dummy2
timestamp                 dummy1        
2014-05-01 09:31:00+00:00 1            3
```